# Foreach loop does not work when required arguments provided

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

My foreach loop doesn't work as expected. I am making a cart that will list all products which are stored in a cookie by a javascript function from another of my webpage. But when I process it and it becomes a var named $items, and I use it in a foreach loop, it gives me an error. The error is: 
`PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in --- on line 127`

I tried to make my code check if $items is an array or not.

My code is for different important sections are:

```
foreach ($things as $item) {
    $q = "SELECT price, item FROM products WHERE id='$item'";
    $r = $dbc->query($q);
    $row = $r->fetch_assoc();
    $price = $row['price'];
    $itemname = $row['item'];
    $items[$itemname] = $price;
    $total = $total + $price;
}
```

I expect this to not return an error. I did things in php like it before many times, but I don't know why it is not working this time.

Comment: The error is about `$things`, not `$items`.

Comment: What is the value of `$things`?

Comment: I meant this is giving me the error, not the $items foreach loop.

Comment: The value og $things is: `$things = $_COOKIE['items'];`

Comment: The error message says an invalid argument was given to `foreach`. `foreach` requires the first argument to be an array, so it means that `$things` is not an array.

Comment: A cookie is always a string.

Comment: If the cookie contains a comma-separated list, you need to use `explode()` to convert it to an array.

Comment: It's probably better to store the cart in a session variable rather than a cookie.

Comment: the thing about this is, it has nothing to do with javascript

Comment: It has to do with Javascript because I have defined the cookie in JavaScript, and I need to know how to make a cookie set in JS that is an array be a string with commas.

Comment: Are you using `JSON.stringify()` in JS to create the cookie from an array? Then use `json_decode($_COOKIE['items'])` to convert it to a PHP array.

Comment: If you're using `array.join(',')` in JS, use `explode(',', $_COOKIE['items'])` in PHP.